# Show only first picture of single product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use this code for load first product gallery image in Woocommerce [not main picture product ] but it loads the first, second, third picture of the product. I just want to load first image of image gallery.

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
    {
  
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

    if ( $attachment_ids && count($attachment_ids) ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_ids[0], 'full');
    }
?>
```

If you are using a recent version of Woocommerce (> 3.0) you should replace:

`$product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();` with `$product->get_gallery_image_ids();`